# Подключение к переменной базы данных с другого активити

Tags: java, activity, sqlite

Подключение к БД идет через DataBaseHelper.java
В MainActivity.java идет подключение к БД через следующий код.

```
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    try {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }
    try {
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    }catch(SQLException sqle){
        throw sqle;
    }
    db = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Теперь добавляется вторая активити со своим джава-файлом. Этот активити тоже будет подключатся к этой же БД. Теперь мне там надо этот код подключения продублировать, т.е. заново подключится к БД? Или же могу сразу подключатся через переменную db сделав его в первом активити public? Если да, то какой из вариантов лучше?

Comment: А вы не пробовали в другой активности создать экземпляр класса (для работы с бд)?

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю, сработает ли, но можно передать в другое активити объект с помощью putExtra.

Но лучше будет закрыть соединение с БД перед переключением в другое активити, при этом действия с базой данных производить из экземляра отдельного класса с помощью геттера.

```
public class MyDbConnect {
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    public MyDbConnect(android.content.Context c) {
        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(c);
        myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(c);
        try {
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }
        try {
            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            throw sqle;
        }
        db = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    }
    public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {return db;}
}
```

Comment: Разве SQLiteDatabase может сериализоваться?

Comment: Нет. Но вы ведь работаете с базой данных, а в коде экземпляр объекта управляет базой данных. То есть не имеет значения какой конкретно экземляр класса управляет БД, а если важно intent.putExtra(...); и this.getIntent().getExtras(); вам в помощь

Comment: так ведь в putextra можно передавать только сериализованные обьекты

Comment: Я так понял, если два активити подключается к одной и той же БД, то лучше эти два активити обединить в одно с двумя лайоутами?

Comment: Нет. Просто не имеет разницы какой экземпляр класса, который подключается к БД, будет взаимодействовать с БД. Если уж надо, создавайте два активити и подключайтесь через разные экземпляры класса MyDbConnect (см. выше ответ). А вообще ещё можете применить паттерн Одиночка/Синглтон, хотя её почему-то не рекомендуют использовать.